# Extract List in Column Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

please help..

```
file.json
[
{"fullname": "mona", "phones": [{"phone": "21323131"}], "areas": [{"area": "Texas"}, {"area": "New York"}] }, 
{"fullname": "joni", "phones": [{"phone": "546465464"},{"phone": "45345353"}], "areas": [{"area": "California"},{"area": "San Jose"}] }
]
```

i have dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('file.json')

print(df.head(2))

Output:

fullname   phones                                          Areas
mona       [{'phone': '21323131'}]                         [{'area': 'Texas'}, {'area': 'New York'}]   
joni       [{'phone': '546465464'},{'phone': '45345353'}]  [{'area': 'California'},{'area': 'San Jose'}]
```

how to extract dataframe to be like this?

```
fullname   phone        Areas
mona       21323131     Texas, New York 
joni       546465464    California, San Jose
joni       45345353     California, San Jose
```

Comment: Can you paste your file.json contents in the question? It will be easier.

Comment: hi @NYCCoder, i have been added json contents in my post.

Comment: @NYCCoder, sorry. I have fixed the sample json contents. please check my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `explode` along with `Series.str.get`:

```
s = df['areas'].explode().str.get('area').groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
d = df.explode('phones').assign(areas=s, phones=lambda x: x['phones'].str.get('phone'))
```

---

```
print(d)

  fullname     phones                 areas
0     mona   21323131       Texas, New York
1     joni  546465464  California, San Jose
1     joni   45345353  California, San Jose
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

exploded_data = [{'fullname': x['fullname'],
                  'phone': p['phone'],
                  'area': a['area']}
                 for x in data for p, a in zip(x['phones'], x['areas'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(exploded_data)
```